# How to re-use NGINX proxy settings in several locations

Tags: security, proxy, nginx, webserver, dry

I have the need to restrict access to certain files based on a query string parameter. I have an NGINX proxy server that sits in front of several other nginx web servers for load balancing. I have decided to enforce this query string parameter at the proxy server level in order to consolidate the configuration changes. This has added a bit of complexity to my setup because the request can not get trapped in the if as it needs to be sent upstream.

```
server {
        listen 443;
        # SSL Settings

        server_name staging.xxxx.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://webdav-cluster;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host            $http_host;
        }

        # Unless the correct application token is passed in as a query parameter
        # then deny access.
        location ~ \/protected\/.*txt$ {
                if ($arg_secret != abc) {
                        return 403;
                }

                proxy_pass http://webdav-cluster;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host            $http_host;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to store those 4 proxy lines in a location or variable and then internally redirect to that with one line? I may also use the same settings in different virtual hosts.

Comment: OP, what did you end up doing? I'm curious about this one as well.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you should use the `include` directive: http://nginx.org/r/include

Comment: Technically correct, but it'd be nice to be able to do it without splitting it into several files for small things.

Comment: Then use your favourite template engine to generate configs. It could be `bash` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's a top Google result and today I found two alternatives which do not require `include`ing a separate file.

As a slightly simpler example, assume I want `/route1` and `/route2` to share the same proxy settings. I can either configure a regex location OR use the `try_files` directive to force a fallback.

#### Use a regex to share proxy config for multiple routes

Source: https://serverfault.com/q/564127/805740

```
location ~ ^/(route1|route2) {
    YOUR_PROXY_CONFIG_HERE
}
```

#### Use `try_files` to force a fallback to a shared proxy config

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/1100562/805740

```
location /route1 {
    try_files "" @fallback
}
location /route2 {
    try_files "" @fallback
}
location @fallback {
    YOUR_PROXY_CONFIG_HERE
}
```

#### Mix and Match

```
location /route1 {
    try_files "" @fallback
}
location ~ ^/(route2|route3) {
    try_files "" @fallback
}
location @fallback {
    YOUR_PROXY_CONFIG_HERE
}
```